# Unable to confirm aws Sns subscription for a http endpoint in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have used the following piece of code to handle the AWS SNS subscription and notification messages. The configured http endpoint is receiving the confirmation message but I am unable to confirm it through code. However the manual confirmation of it is happening by visiting the "subscription url" from the logged console message.

I have configured the aws and sns part as mentioned below:

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.loadFromPath(__dirname + '/awsConfig.json');
var sns = new aws.SNS();
```

This is the following function I am using for handling http endpoint messages.

```
function handleIncomingMessage(msgType, msgData) {
    if (msgType === 'SubscriptionConfirmation') {
        //confirm the subscription.
        console.log("Subscription Confirmation Message--->"+msgData);
        sns.confirmSubscription({
            TopicArn: msgData.TopicArn
        }, onAwsResponse);
    } else if (msgType === 'Notification') {
        console.log("Notification has arrived");
    } else {
        console.log('Unexpected message type ' + msgType);
    }
}
```

Here the sns.confirmSubscription isn't working, Is there any solution/work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to pass a `Token` field in the `confirmSubscription` parameters as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#confirmSubscription-property).